# mouseleave for two elements to hide another div

Tags: jquery

I need my submenu div to only disappear when both li item and the submenu itself are not hovered.

CSS solution will not work here as I need to use first-child hover and the submenu div is not a child element.

I have searched the forums but can't find a solution for this when the submenu is not a child of the li item.

HTML:

```
<ul id="top-menu"> 
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 2</li>
<li>item3</li>
</ul>

<!-- somewhere else in DOM (not directly after or child of menu) -->

<div id="#menu1_expansion">
sub menu1 content
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#top-menu li:nth-child(1)').hover(
    function()
    { 
        $('#menu1_expansion').stop();

        if ($('#menu1_expansion:hidden'))
        { 
            $('#menu1_expansion').show();
        }

    }
);
$('#menu1_expansion').mouseleave( function(){ $('#menu1_expansion').hide(); });
});
```

CSS:

```
#menu1_expansion {display:none; position:absolute;}
```

Currently this gets the submenu to appear on li item hover and the  submenu disappears when mouseleave but I need the submenu to hide when both it AND the li item is mouseleave - can anyone advise how to do it? thanks.

Comment: any valid reasons for not putting your `#menu1_expansion`  inside the li & do that in 2 lines of css ?

Comment: hi, i'm adding this to a CMS (sitecore) so unable to place the submenu inside the li item

Comment: wrong you can append it inside the li with js (if you don't know how how to customize the server script)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the #menu1_expansion once and keep it visible: try mouseover() instead of hover.

The hover function is only triggered when you hover the object, and is not triggered when you do not point at the element.

Comment: Hi, I've used your suggestion and changed hover to mouseover() however still need away of hiding the submenu div when both the li item and submenu are mouseleave

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a way to get it working, the code is below if it can help anyone else:

```
                $(document).ready(function () {
var count = 0;
$('#top-menu li:nth-child(1), #menu_expansion').mouseenter(function(){
    count++;
    $('#menu_expansion').show();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    count--;
    if (count == 0) { 
        $('#menu_expansion').hide();
    }
});


});
```